# c: can typedef-d enum check for the actual values?

Tags: c, enums, typedef, type-definition

```
typedef enum
{
   FLAG_P_INVALID = -1,
   FLAG_P_ONE,
   FLAG_P_TWO,
   FLAG_M_INVALID = -1,
   FLAG_M_ONE,
   FLAG_M_TWO
} my_type;
```

However compiler (`gcc-8.3.1`) allows the following:

```
my_type t = 7;
```

I expected that typedef'd `enum` would allow to check the actual values. Is it not the case?

Comment: Why did you expect that? `typedef` just introduces another name. It does not create a strong type. It does not affect the type that it refers to at all; it just adds another name for it. The real type is some integer one either way. C does not have strongly typed, non-convertible enums.

Comment: So it is a programmer's responsibility to validate the input?

Comment: @Mark - yes.  The C philosophy is that the programmer is in the best position to know whether a runtime check needs to be performed, and if it is, is smart enough to write it.  The language won't do those checks for you.  Enumerations in C are not high-level abstractions like they are in Java or C#.  They're just a convenient way to define sets of values that aren't necessarily ordered.

Comment: @Mark Yes. For example, some enumerators are used as bitmasks, so the enum _must_ allow values that are not discretely declared (in fact, any value that can fit into the bits of all declared enumerators, in an implementation-defined integral type).